# can't access my internet?.but it shows connected

Tags: windows

i am no expert so need your expert advice.my internet company says everything is okay from their side.and yeah so does the modem link. it shows connected on my system but when  surf ,website doesn't load.

it sometimes says: 1.DNS server failure.
2: page not found.
3.check your internet connection.

but on the other hand my torrentloader is working fine as used to. its downloading (i checked if its working or not).

when i reset my modem,net goes fine for next 5 min,but again after it slump comes.and i can't access it.

i am using D-link router.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. The cause for me was the router. We had the same symptoms, browsing would work for a matter of minutes then fall over and bring up the errors you mentioned. However, I noticed that I could access IP addresses directly but the web address would fail for the same site. It was a network wide problem.

Firstly get the IP address of a site when your internet is working from the DNS lookup. You can use **nslookup** (e.g. nslookup www.google.com) or **ping** (e.g. ping www.google.com) to get the IP. Then when you're internet is "broken," try the web address and the direct IP address. If the IP addres loads the page but the web address doesn't, it's a DNS issue.

Second, assuming your computer is set up to automatically receive DNS information, log in to your router and look in the status page. Find the primary and secondary DNS servers that your ISP passed to your router and note them down.

While your internet is "broken," manually apply your ISPs DNS settings to your computer's network settings and try again. You can also use Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) if you like. If that works, then it's your router.

These were the steps I took and discovered that my router essentially couldn't retain DNS routing information and we'd cooked it. Time for a new one.

While it might not solve your problem, it may help narrow down a cause or eliminate a suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Quit the torrent package, open a command prompt and try ipconfig /flushdns . If that does nothing then create a new login user in control panel - login as that user and try your internet connection again.